# What is the compiled size of Semtech LoRaMAC node libraries?

Tags: microcontroller, library, firmware, lora

I'm trying to determine if the microcontroller I intend to use for a project will have enough flash memory for my preferred SDK and also the LoRaMAC libraries.

Does anyone know roughly what the compiled size of the Semtech LoRaMAC library is for a LoRaWAN node?
The documentation doesn't say this, so I was hoping someone with experience of implementing it might know better.

Link to the library: https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node

Additionally if anyone has any advice on implementing this on a CC1310 it would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the size of the library you provided but compiled size of this one: https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic is about 30K.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen the arduino port for it but hoped it was a bit bloated compared to what a lower level implementation might be.